# Is it possible to avoid the "AudioContext was not allowed to start" alert?

Tags: javascript, audiocontext, webkitaudiocontext

I faced a browser policy problem "The AudioContext was not allowed to start. It must be resumed (or created) after a user gesture on the page."
I wanted to execute that below code when page loaded.
So, I tried to mock the user click gesture using a hidden button and load event listener but failed.

Is it possible??

```
let my_array = [];
function my_function() {
  let audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
  let analyser = audioCtx.createAnalyser();
  let oscillator = audioCtx.createOscillator();

  oscillator.type = "triangle"; // Set oscillator to output triangle wave
  oscillator.connect(analyser); // Connect oscillator output to analyser input
  let gain = audioCtx.createGain();
  let scriptProcessor = audioCtx.createScriptProcessor(4096, 1, 1);
  analyser.connect(scriptProcessor); // Connect analyser output to scriptProcessor input
  scriptProcessor.connect(gain); // Connect scriptProcessor output to gain input
  gain.connect(audioCtx.destination); // Connect gain output to audiocontext destination
  gain.gain.value = 0; // Disable volume

  scriptProcessor.onaudioprocess = function (bins) {
    bins = new Float32Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
    analyser.getFloatFrequencyData(bins);
    for (var i = 0; i < bins.length; i = i + 1) {
      my_array.push(bins[i]);
    }
    analyser.disconnect();
    scriptProcessor.disconnect();
    gain.disconnect();

  };
  // audioCtx.resume().then(() => {
  //   oscillator.start(0);
  // });
  oscillator.start(0);
}
```

Comment: What would be the point of such restriction if we could bypass it like that? Make your users interact with the page, for instance show them a play button that they have to click.

Comment: Ah, What a silly question.... I added user interaction on my page. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

### Update

There is a way to enable sound permission for the site in Chrome (the lock icon in the address bar, then Site settings). Yet in this case you cannot query if the permission has been granted, and hasBeenActive is not set. So the solution below doesn't actually work, unless knowing for sure people have not given manual permission to the site to play sounds.

### The old answer

Just for anyone else getting this warning and considering it annoying. There is a way to determine if the user has made a gesture by calling navigator.userActivation.hasBeenActive. In other words, if you create an AudioContext (or any other API that is restricted by this) only when this field is true, you will not get the warning.

More here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UserActivation/hasBeenActive - sticky activation (for AudioContext)

More here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UserActivation/isActive - transient activation (see the list of APIs in the last link)

And here: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#user-activation-gated-apis

And here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/User_activation